# React Native: Setting params while switching bottom navigation tabs

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm using bottom navigation in one of my apps, and have run into a problem.

I want to send some event to the cloud whenever user uses bottom navigation to land on a page, let's say A1.

Here's my code:

```
const tabBarConfigs = {
  lazy: true,
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarComponent: props => <AppBottomTab {...props} />,
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: Fonts.Colors.transparent,
    },
    activeTintColor: Fonts.Colors.reddishPink,
    inactiveTintColor: Fonts.Colors.fullBlack,
    labelStyle: { fontFamily: Fonts.Medium, fontSize: 10, marginTop: -2 },
    upperCaseLabel: true,
    allowFontScaling: false,
    showIcon: true,
  },
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
      defaultHandler();
      navigation.setParams({
        eventData: {
          source: "bottom_nav",
        },
      });
      if (navigation.isFocused()) {
        const scrollToTop = navigation.getParam("scrollToTop", null);
        if (scrollToTop) {
          scrollToTop();
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
```

The problem is, when the user lands from any other touchpoint (other than bottom navigation) then also the eventData is already set in navigation. How to avoid that ?

Have been struggling with this for 3 days. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: There are two dependencies: "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6" and "react-navigation": "^4.1.1". @Roy.B